# Split a String into words

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm looking for some help with creating an array from user String input. I tried with the *Split(" ")* but as far as I know Scanner deletes the spaces between the words so that didn't work.

Again I'm looking to create an array which would have single words in every "space". So if the user input is:

```
"My name is John"
```

the array would look like this:

```
array[0] = My
array[1] = name
array[2] = is
```

and so on

Comment: So, do you want the result to keep the spaces? I.e. should it be `"My "` or `"My"`?

Comment: Consider using scanner.nextLine() , it won't remove white spaces, then use the split explained in the answers .

Comment: You can use [StirngTonkenizer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/java_util_stringtokenizer.htm) also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scanner.nextLine()` See [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) and then use following:

```
String urString = scanner.nextLine();
String[] array = urString .split(" ");
```

You can use `urString.split("\\s+")` from [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

> **s** means A whitespace character
>   **s+** means one or many whitespaces